# Requested URL not found when refresh the page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, google-app-engine, react-router

I'm developing an application using react js and nodejs.When I run the application in local machine it works properly as a example

1. localhost:3000/Instagram/Services
2. localhost:3000

When I refresh the above URLs, it shows the correct web page.
I deploy this application in Google App Engine and when I refresh the below page it shows that the requested URL was not found. Can any one let me know the reason for this?

1. www.mydomain.com/Instagram/Services

Comment: What do you see for the failed requests in the developer console logs?

Comment: Provide the app.yaml too. It could be that configuration of the file is causing the issue.

Answer (score -1):

It's probably because you're using browserRouter and haven't configured an appropriate handler correctly in your app.yaml. You can find detailed info about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref)

You might put there something like this:

```
handlers:
- url: /(.*)
static_files: /index.html
upload: /index.html
```

You could also use hashRouter but then you'd need to put a /#/ in each route.

Comment: let me know that below is wrong


runtime: nodejs8
handlers:
- url: /api/.*
  # secure: always
  # redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto
- url: /.*
  static_files: build/index.html
  upload: build/index.html
- url: /
  static_dir: build

Comment: take that static_dir out of there